# Xamarin indie license - publish an APK

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have used search at StackOwerflow, but got no answer.

The problem is - I have bought an Indie license for Xamarin Android and I can not create an APK package any more. When I used a trial version everything worked well.

(The publish APK menu is not highlighted)

Have anyone seen such problem before and how it can be solved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, the answer is simple. Publishing it for the case if someone will face such problem.

**Just need to swith Project-Active configuration to Release.**